# SwaggerUI/YAML - Parser error bad indentation of a mapping entry

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

[Screenshot of Swagger Editor & code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84vIn.png)
Hi, I am new to API testing and Swagger and am getting this parser error message in the Swagger Editor and I am having problems locating the problem.

Bellow is a copy paste of the code.

The error message is "bad indentation of a mapping entry" and is displayed where --> `in: "path"`.

I followed this YouTube Tutorial --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoUl9_NWdqQ

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 'v1.0'
  title: 'Random'

# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
basePath: /GroovySalmon/DOITNOW/v1.0
schemes:
  - https

paths:
  /vehicles/{id}/data_request/drive_state:
    get:
      operationId: "drive_state"
      description: "Returns the driving and position state of the vehicle"
      parameters:
      **-name: "id"**
          in: "path"
          description: "The ID number of the car"
          required: true
          type: "String"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success"
          schema:
            properties:
              shift_state:
                type: "String"
                example: "sport"
              speed:
                type: "number"
                format: "double"
                example: 94.5
              latitude:
                description: "degrees north of the equator"
                type: "number"
                format: "double"
                example: 37.345
              longitude:
                description: "degrees west of the prime meridian"
                type: "number"
                format: "double"
                example: 122.1243
              heading:
                description: "integer compass heading"
                type: "integer"
                format: "int32"
                minimum: 0
                maximum: 359
                example: 4
              gps_as_of:
                description: "unix timestamp of gps fix"
                example: "1234934991232"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
type: "String"
```

to

```
type: "string"
```

Note the lowercase "s" in "string".

All OpenAPI [`type`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types) values are lowercase and case-sensitive.

Also, make sure there are spaces after `-` in parameter definitions (and in YAML lists in general), and that the indentation is correct:

```
- name: "id"
  in: "path"
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't do the trick though. :=)

Comment: @Dan it seems that there are also indentation and spacing issues, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Do'h! Yeah, that answer saved the day. Thanks for helpin'!

Comment: @Dan Glad to help! Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247) this answer to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Done! Thx again.